# How to add a clickable option to a CategoryCard on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am wondering if it is possible to add a functionality of clicking the CategoryCard and redirect to another flutter screen.

My code is the following:

```
CategoryCard(
                      title: 'Wifi',
                      imgSrc: 'assets/img/wifi.png',
                    ),
                    CategoryCard(
                      title: 'Key',
                      imgSrc: 'assets/img/signIn.png',
                    ),
```

And I am wondering how to make each of these CategoryCards clickable.
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to wrap your `CategoryCard` with an `InkWell` or GestureDetector. The difference between `InkWell` and `GestureDetector` is that `InkWell` will create a ripple effect when it is pressed while `GestureDetector` does not.

`InkWell` Solution:

```
InkWell(
   child: CategoryCard(
               title: 'Wifi',
               imgSrc: 'assets/img/wifi.png',
             ),
   onTap:(){
      print("It works");
    }
),
```

`GestureDetector` Solution:

```
GestureDetector(
   child: CategoryCard(
               title: 'Wifi',
               imgSrc: 'assets/img/wifi.png',
             ),
   onTap:(){
      print("It works");
    }
),
```